# CouchDb reduction on two keys

Tags: couchdb

I've a document in my CouchDB which is structured like this:

```
{date: 1234567, authors: ['Foo', 'Bar']}
```

My goal is to figure out how "active" a certain author is. Doing it with the following works nice.

```
map: function(doc) {
  doc.authors.forEach(function(name) {
    emit(name, 1);
  });
},
reduce: function(keys, values) {
  return sum(values);
}
```

But now I'm wondering how I'd be able to also put an (dynamic) limit on the date: field?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `date` in the key:

map:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.authors && doc.date) {
    doc.authors.forEach(function (author) {
      emit([author, doc.date], 1);
    });
  }
}
```

reduce:

```
_sum
```

and query with (properly url-encoded):

```
startkey=['author',STARTDATE]&endkey=['author',ENDDATE]&group_level=1
```

If you want more then one author with a single query, you can't use a reduce function, because the size of the result of reduce must not depend from the number of rows. Here are a couple of possible solutions:

- The most general solution is to use [list functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List#Listing_Views_with_CouchDB_0.10_and_later). However keep in mind that they are heavy on the server because the result is not saved on disk as with map/reduce.
- If you have predefined periods (for example months or years), you can emit a row for each period to which doc.date belongs to, and put the period as first element in the key.

For example use the following map function (same reduce as before):

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.authors && doc.date) {
    var periods = getPeriod(doc.date);
    doc.authors.forEach(function (author) {
      periods.forEach(function (period) {
        emit([period, author], 1);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

and query with:

```
startkey=[PERIOD]&endkey=[PERIOD,{}]&group_level=exact
```

Here `getPeriod()` is a function that you must define to get an array of periods to which a given date belongs to.

Comment: ok sounds reasonable but in this case I'd be reduced to one author per query - right? So I won't be able to get "all" authors during that timeframe?

Comment: You said: «My goal is to figure out how "active" a certain author is.» And that is what I've answered to. If you want all the authors with a single query, you can't use a reduce function, because it must return a scalar value (more precisely a small fixed size value that does not grow with the number of result rows.) I've added a couple notes with possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks - adding the period was the keyword for me - thanks that you pushed me in the right direction :)

Comment: Can't tell you how much your answer opened my eyes. Just learned the how to utilize the grouping levels, additional functions, why your endkey contained {} and what list functions are. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @pagid, I'm glad to have been helpful. It took me a lot of time to grasp all these concepts. CouchDB lacks good documentation: the wiki is incomplete, ["The Definitive guide"](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/index.html) has only basic info, most of blog posts are outdated. It will improve, but, for now, be prepared for a long journey.